# How to copy embedded third party frameworks to user Library/framework folder or Project folder when archive on MacOs projects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks

I have third party .framework in my MacOs project. When I try to run, I get error;
dyld: Library not loaded:   Reason: image not found

In Build Phases=>Embedded Frameworks, Code Sign On Copy is checked, and Destination Dropdown selected "Frameworks".

When I change Destination dropdown to "Products Directory", Xcode is running the project.

Also, the .framework checked Embed & Sign in General=>Frameworks,Libraries, and Embedded Contents section.

But if I want to export or archive Distribute App to installer, it is not running. Probably app is looking for .framework in /Library/Framework folder of user.

So, I need to Run Script or something else, when I try to install or run exported app, third party framework should be copied to /Library/Framework folder.

Or Another Solution; can I embed this framework to app contents?